# How to get object from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, return

I am trying to get changed data object passed in function countAmountInOneWeek
but when i try to get it i get message undefined.

This is for counting sum in past 7 days, after counting the sum i am deleting first seven days so i could count 7 days amount once more.

```js
[{ "date": "2016-01-05", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_in", "operation": { "amount": 200.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-06", "user_id": 2, "user_type": "juridical", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 300.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-06", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 30000, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-07", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 1000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-07", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 100.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 100.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 2, "user_type": "juridical", "type":
"cash_in", "operation": { "amount": 1000000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 3, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 1000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-02-15", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 300.00, "currency": "EUR" } }]
```

```js
readJSON = function() {
  fs.readFile(args, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(obj);
    printResult(obj);
    var sum = countAmountInOneWeek(obj);
    console.log("SUM " + sum[0]);
    console.log("SUM " + sum[1].data);
  });
}
```

I need to get changed data object and sum

```
function countAmountInOneWeek(data) {
  var recordRemoveIndex;
  var sum = data[0].operation.amount;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date1 = new Date(data[0].date);
    var date2 = new Date(data[i].date);

    const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    const difference = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    //console.log(diffTime + " Time " + difference);

    if (difference < 7) {
      sum = sum + data[i].operation.amount;
      recordRemoveIndex = i;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= recordRemoveIndex; i++) {
    data.shift();
  }
  console.log(data);
  return [sum, data];
}
```

```js
var data = [{ "date": "2016-01-05", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_in", "operation": { "amount": 200.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-06", "user_id": 2, "user_type": "juridical", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 300.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-06", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 30000, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-07", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 1000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-07", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 100.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 100.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 2, "user_type": "juridical", "type":
"cash_in", "operation": { "amount": 1000000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 3, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 1000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
{ "date": "2016-02-15", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
"cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 300.00, "currency": "EUR" } }]

function countAmountInOneWeek(data) {
  var recordRemoveIndex;
  var sum = data[0].operation.amount;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date1 = new Date(data[0].date);
    var date2 = new Date(data[i].date);

    const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    const difference = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    //console.log(diffTime + " Time " + difference);

    if (difference < 7) {
      sum = sum + data[i].operation.amount;
      recordRemoveIndex = i;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= recordRemoveIndex; i++) {
    data.shift();
  }
  return [sum, data];
}

console.log(countAmountInOneWeek(data))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @NickParsons How? The function is inside the callback

Comment: @mplungjan I was thinking they're trying to call `readJSON` and then trying to return from there maybe...

Comment: @Emilis Can you give examples of the value of `data` -- not the json object but the string you read from the file?

Comment: @chatnoir added file in description.

Comment: I made you a snippet - what is the expected output? If correct then the issue is the fs.readFile - any console errors? You are normally not allowed to use fs.readFile on a web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `readJSON` function, change

```
   console.log("SUM " + sum[0]);
   console.log("SUM " + sum[1].data);
```

to

```
console.log(sum[0]); //1032700 
console.log(sum[1][0]); // because sum[1] is [ { date: '2016-02-15',user_id: 1,user_type: 'natural',type: 'cash_out',operation: {amount: 300, currency: 'EUR' } } ]
```

You can then use or modify json2 as needed.

The below code shows that it will return the proper values

```js
let json = [{ "date": "2016-01-05", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
        "cash_in", "operation": { "amount": 200.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-06", "user_id": 2, "user_type": "juridical", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 300.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-06", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 30000, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-07", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 1000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-07", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 100.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 100.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 2, "user_type": "juridical", "type":
            "cash_in", "operation": { "amount": 1000000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-01-10", "user_id": 3, "user_type": "natural", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 1000.00, "currency": "EUR" } },
    { "date": "2016-02-15", "user_id": 1, "user_type": "natural", "type":
            "cash_out", "operation": { "amount": 300.00, "currency": "EUR" } }] ;

//this code should be found within readJSON()
//we just run it straight away using json data above
//********************

var sum = countAmountInOneWeek(json); 
console.log(sum[0]); //1032700 
console.log(sum[1][0]); // because sum[1] is [ { date: '2016-02-15',user_id: 1,user_type: 'natural',type: 'cash_out',operation: {amount: 300, currency: 'EUR' } } ]
//********************

function countAmountInOneWeek(data){
    var recordRemoveIndex;
    var sum = data[0].operation.amount;
    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
        var date1 = new Date(data[0].date);
        var date2 = new Date(data[i].date);

        const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        const difference = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        //console.log(diffTime + " Time " + difference);

        if(difference < 7){
            sum = sum + data[i].operation.amount;
            recordRemoveIndex = i;
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i <= recordRemoveIndex; i++){
        data.shift();
    }
    //console.log(data);
    return [sum, data];
}
```

Comment: @Emilis you're most welcome! I've edited it to use your syntax instead of mine,  changing `sum[1].data` to `sum[1][0]`.